# Alter SQL Query in Power Query with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently stuck trying to figure out how to use VBA to alter a power query.

Right now when i do this and I get

```
debug.print thisworkbook.queries("Query1").formula
let
    Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=Netezza", "select * from table1")
in
    Source
```

I'm trying to find out how I'm supposed to alter the formula to pass a parameter to the where clause (ie where car = "toyota") at the end of the query, and then refresh the query.

When I tried to alter the .Formula but maybe I didn't enter the string correctly because it broke the connection and lost the ODBC.

I'm using Excel2016.

Can you please show me the proper syntax to alter this query and then refresh? Thanks for your help!